# What is the solution to arctan(i)

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

I have no idea how to anywhere with this problem, can somebody please help me answer this question, I am a beginner at trig and am looking for some help

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ArcTan%5Bi%5D

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Extension_to_complex_plane

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose that $\tan z=i$. That means that $\sin z=i\cos z$. Then
$$\sin^2 z+\cos^2 z=(i\cos z)^2+\cos^2z=(i^2+1)\cos^2 z=0.$$
But
$$\sin^2 z+\cos^2 z=1.$$

Therefore there is no complex number with $\tan z=i$ (or with $\tan z=-i$).